# Inconsistent received bytes on AWS application load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm investigating why there was a peak in *NetworkIn* of my application load balancer.

[image]

So I enabled the access log of the load balancer, and sum the [`received_bytes`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html) of all the requests of `2020-08-03 11:44:00 UTC+0800`.

> received_bytes:
>
> The size of the request, in bytes, received from the client
> (requester). For HTTP requests, this includes the headers. For
> WebSockets, this is the total number of bytes received from the client
> on the connection.

But the total bytes I get from the logs are just 458355 bytes, which is far less than 476.966MB in the picture above.

[image]

I use excel's function [`SUM(K:K)`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sum-function-043e1c7d-7726-4e80-8f32-07b23e057f89) to calculate the total number of bytes in the logs.

The definition of NetworkIn can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/viewing_metrics_with_cloudwatch.html).

> The number of bytes received on all network interfaces by the
> instance. This metric identifies the volume of incoming network
> traffic to a single instance.
>
> The number reported is the number of bytes received during the period.
> If you are using basic (five-minute) monitoring, you can divide this
> number by 300 to find Bytes/second. If you have detailed (one-minute)
> monitoring, divide it by 60.
>
> Units: Bytes

Why are they inconsistent?

Comment: NetworkIn does not mean the received bytes for the requests.

Comment: @Lamanus, What are the differences between NetworkIn and the total recevied_bytes?

Comment: it is for the requests or just data transfer, maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*NetworkIn* contains all the data transmitted to the EC2 instances behind the load balancer.

In my case, this includes all the data that the EC2s receive from a MySQL database.

The data transmitted from the database to the EC2s is not included in *received_bytes*, because it doesn't go through the load balancer.

That explains why the bytes of *NetworkIn* and the bytes of *received_bytes* are different.

The log of network interface can be enabled by clicking `Services` -> `EC2` -> `Network Interfaces` -> `pick a network interface` -> `Flow Logs` tab -> `Create flow log`.